# NameError: name 'msg' is not defined

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, publish-subscribe

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global msg
    #print("message received " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    #print("message topic=",message.topic)
    #print("message qos=",message.qos)
    #print("message retain flag=",message.retain)
    msg = str(message.payload)

broker_address="10.87.7.27"
print("creating new instance")
client = mqtt.Client("P1") #create new instance
client.on_message= on_message #attach function to callback
print("connecting to broker")
client.connect(broker_address,1883) #connect to broker
client.loop_start() #start the loop
print("Subscribing to topic","home/kitchen/output/lights/set")
client.subscribe("Sekurit_KTBlower_Optimizer_write")
time.sleep(10) 

print(msg)
dict_str = msg.decode("UTF-8")
#jsonload = json.loads(dict_str)
mydata = ast.literal_eval(dict_str)
Lowerpredict = mydata["Lowerpredict"]
Upperpredict = mydata["Upperpredict"]

print(Lowerpredict,UpperPredict)
client.loop_stop() #stop the loop
```

i am getting an error as "NameError: name 'msg' is not defined"
till time.sleep the code is running after that i get this error in dict_str.If i declare msg globally and msg = None outside the function i am not getting mydata['lowerpredict'] and mydata['Upperpredict']...the code exact error is in dict_str.
anyone have a solution?

Comment: Just what it says - `msg` is not defined within the global scope. It is only defined inside the function scope.

Comment: A [mcve] would help... your code misses the import statements (and maybe more?)

Comment: Would please declared mes globally, before function

Answer (score 2):

You need to either

1. declare `msg` globally:

```
msg = None

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    # ...

    global msg
    msg = str(message.payload)

# ...

client = mqtt.Client("P1")
client.on_message= on_message

# ... 

print(msg)
```

2. put the code accessing `msg` inside a function:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    # ...

    on_message_received(client, userdata, str(message.payload))

def on_message_received(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg)

    # ...

client = mqtt.Client("P1")
client.on_message= on_message
```

Comment: even i declare it globally i get the same error

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68950640/edit) including your updated attempt.